# Increasing the PNG quality in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, png, android-vectordrawable

I am a beginner in Android Development and am trying to understand how to use PNG or vector drawable (`XML`) files in my Android App. To practice, I create an App with both images below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcEl.jpg (link to see the res repository)

The purpose was to compare the quality of both structures. The result can be viewed below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL4qX.png (link to see the result in the device emulator)

In my device, the image above represents a PNG file while the other (the image below with better quality) represents the vector drawable file.
My question is simple: **is there some way to increase the quality of the PNG file in my device activity**?
Note: I am using Kotlin and a simple `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: simply provide a higher quality png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing high quality image you have to choose higher quality image but have to do following for loading that image in all types of devices.

Suppose you have a `png` image

1. You have to choose the higher quality image for import like 1920 x 1080.
2. Then You have to use batch drawable importer to import that image into your android studio project
3. It will create appropriate versions of that high-quality image to show on different devices.
4. Use Glider for loading images it will show images effectively.

Here is link for how to use batch drawable importer:

https://youtu.be/toHF8fOceoc

https://akexorcist.dev/android-drawable-importer-plugin/

It will create folders and images of all sizes

```
xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px
xxhdpi: 960x1600 px
xhdpi: 640x960 px
hdpi: 480x800 px
mdpi: 320x480 px
ldpi: 240x320 px
```